# Creating Image Url from blob in fastify backend creates invalid URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express, fastify

I have a list of entities where each entity contains `N` amount of blobs/images.
The list of entities can be `M` long. To avoid an extra `M*N` calls i need to create the image URL in the retrieval of the entities as shown below.

[image: Artchitecture]

However when I write:

---

FrontEndExample.tsx

```
    const blob = new Blob([img_uint8], { type: 'image/gif' });
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return imageUrl;
```

i get
`blob:http://localhost:3000/75d3c6a1-1f07-4371-b413-a742aee76b37`

But in the backend i get: `blob:nodedata:a9c2c7ec-b32f-45a6-aee8-50c14460788d`

---

## The issue:

Writing `URL.createObjectURL(blob);` in the front-end gives me an `blob:${url}/guid`, however the backend returns `blob:nodenv/guid`.

Trying to access the backend image with blob:localhost:port/guid does not yield a result.

how can I get the correct URL from the backend?

Comment: Object url's area a convenience - they aren't a way to transmit huge files using very small guid's - that would be the ultimate compression if you could!! if you have a file on the server that you need to read on the client, you have to send the whole file, not a convenient short representation of it

Comment: So you are unable to convert a blob to fileurl, inherently publishing the image on the backend and then displaying it in the front-end? @JaromandaX

Comment: not sure what you're saying ... an object url is relevant where it is created only ... it is not transmissable in any useful way - at least not for what you want to do - I guess you can create an object URL, send it to a client, it can request it as some later time, and you then send it the file it represents - seems a convoluted way of doing things though

Comment: Give the docs a read: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlcreateobjecturlblob
That API is experimental and it will retain the blob into the server memory. We can find a workaround to get your code working, but you will hit **out of memory** error if you have M*N blobs

Comment: i see, thanks guys. seems like i will have to retrieve every blob individually and create the urls in the client.

Appreaciate the input ManuelSpigolon & Jaromanda X